# Nativescript-vue watch for props

Tags: nativescript, watch, nativescript-vue, vue-props

I have a problem in my ns-vue app with watching. I have the app which is based on this drawer navigation template https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/@nativescript/template-drawer-navigation-vue. I want use geolocation for whole app, so I placed this module to *DrawerContent.vue*.
In this file, I am passing props to other modules:

```
onNavigationItemTap(component) {
  this.$navigateTo(component, {
    clearHistory: true,
    props:{
      latitude: this.latitude,
      longitude: this.longitude,
    }
   });
   utils.closeDrawer();
}
```

**latitude** and **longitude** are updated regularly.

and on *Home.vue* I have:

```
props:['latitude','longitude'],
...
....
watch:{
   latitude:()=>{
      console.log('LAT change detected')
      }
}
```

but this is not working. I tried lot of options from the whole web, for example:

```
watch: {
   $props: {
      handler() {
        this.parseData();
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
  }
}
```

or

```
watch:{
   '$props':()=>{
      ......
     }
}
```

but still not working.

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Props passed through Nativescript navigation might not be reactive, anyway I wouldn't let the drawer component handle this feature.

If you're using Vuex, you could move these properties (or the whole logic) to the store and fetch them in your component through computed properties. You could also set up a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) if your code can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

vue props are not reactive https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html
but you can pass an `object` as a property containing `latitude` and `longitude`:

```
data () {
    return {
      location: {
          latitude: ...,
          longitude: ...,
      }
    };
},
...
this.$set(this.location, 'latitude', latitude);
...
onNavigationItemTap(component) {
  this.$navigateTo(component, {
    clearHistory: true,
    props:{
      location: this.location
    }
   });
   utils.closeDrawer();
}
```

and the watcher:

```
props:['location'],
...
watch:{
   'location.latitude' () {
      console.log('LAT change detected')
      }
}
```

Comment: OK, I`ll try it. Thanks

Comment: ... not working. I think that TomG is right - props passed throught $navigateTo() are not reactive because of they are passed only once ( when $navigateTo is called).

Comment: there are probably an error on your code - the props should be `props:['location']` not `props:['latitude','longitude']`